# "TextWriter sw" Formatação

Tags: c#

Estou usando o "TextWriter sw" para enviar para o Word transformando as textboxs em doc o problema  que eu preciso de alguma formatação. Como faço para configurar tamanho do parágrafo, espaço entre linhas e etc...
O código que estou usando para mandar para o Word é similar ao abaixo:

```
String strtxt22 = textBox7.Text;
String strtxt23 = textBox8.Text;
TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\\Gold Business - Cadastro Funcionário.doc");
sw.WriteLine(strtxt22);
sw.WriteLine(strtxt23);
```

Comment: Não conheço o formato do arquivo do Word, mas não poderá simplesmente mandar um texto. Tem que escrever um binário no formato correto. É extremamente complicado. Provavelmente preferirá usar alguma biblioteca. Se for `.docx` é um pouco mais fácil, só um pouco.

Comment: Pelo método acima transforma os textos das textboxs em doc eu já testei aqui o que eu gostaria de saber é como fazer é formatar; tamanho do parágrafo, espaço entre linhas e etc...

Comment: Não transforma em formato do `doc`, transforma em `rtf`. Funcionar não significa que está certo e só existe o certo e o errado. "funcionou no meu meu computador na situação específica que eu testei" não é uma opção. Ajudei no que eu podia.

Answer (score 0):

Existe um package no Nuget que se chama "DocX". Ele faz exatamente o que você precisa.

Exemplo de código:

```
var paraFormat = new Formatting();
paraFormat.FontFamily = new System.Drawing.FontFamily("Calibri");
paraFormat.Size = 10D;

 doc.InsertParagraph(headlineText, false, headLineFormat);
 doc.InsertParagraph(paraOne, false, paraFormat);
```

Fonte: [Exemplo tirado do codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660478/Csharp-Create-and-Manipulate-Word-Documents-Progra)